# App that is rude to you if you mistype your password

Tags: software-recommendation

There's an app, that when you type your password incorrectly in terminal it responds with something cheeky or downright rude.

What's the name of the app?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2012/05/making-sudo-throw-insults-instead-of.html)?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Roger wilco. ;)

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen my upvote reset it only to 0. - Sorry ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way to tell the sudo command to answer in a more "rude" way than usual. To change that, add the `Defaults insults` option into the file `/etc/sudoers`:

```
sudo visudo
```

add the line

```
Defaults insults
```

and save the file.

Entering a wrong password would then output something like:

```
sudo passwd root
[sudo] password for user: (entering wrong password)
Have a gorilla...
```

;) have fun...

P.S. The file containing the list of insults is in the source code of sudo `plugins/sudoers/insults.h`, which you then would have to recompile yourself.

Comment: See https://github.com/mer-tools/sudo/blob/master/plugins/sudoers/insults.h

Comment: Better use `sudo visudo` to edit `sudoers`, it will do a safety check before accepting the change.

Comment: @byte-commander you just removed the *phun* in the anser. Now the answer doesn't pass the turing test any longer... ;)